# Question on syntax related to Python Dictionary implementation

Tags: python, dictionary

Could anyone please help me on understanding the below code. A dictionary is implemented with Names and phone numbers as the key value pair. I couldn't exactly understand how phone_book = {k: v for k,v in name_numbers} this syntax works

```
n = int(input())
name_numbers = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
phone_book = {k: v for k,v in name_numbers}
while True:
 try:
    name = input()
    if name in phone_book:
        print('%s=%s' % (name, phone_book[name]))
    else:
        print('Not found')
except:
    break
```

Comment: Look into dict comprehensions, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/, A better way to do it would be simply doing,
```phone_book = dict(name_numbers)```

Comment: name_numbers which is a list comprhension is like a for loop looping n time . the code assumes each input line contains name and phone number separated by space. so for n = 2 name_numbers would look like ```[['foo',4343], ['bar',5454]]``` then phone book is another dict comprhension creating dictionary out each pairs in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `phone_book = {k: v for k,v in name_numbers}` should be equivalent to:

```
phone_book = {}
for k,v in name_numbers:
    phone_book[k] = v
```

but shortened using dictionary comprehension.
Check out https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

when you use `input().split()`, it automatically returns a list. Therefore `name_numbers` will be a list of lists. `phone_book` will expect each list to have two elements, the first element will become the key and the second element will become the value. According to your code, the first line should have the number of records, and the following lines should have the name and the number separated by a space. When `split()` is applied to each line, it gets converted to a list with two elements (the name and the number).

If your code is like this:

```py
name_numbers = [['Arnold', '555675'], ['Jacob', '764439'], ['Melissa', '964468']]
phone_book = {k: v for k,v in name_numbers}
print(phone_book)
```

Your output would look like this:

> {'Melissa': '964468', 'Jacob': '764439', 'Arnold': '555675'}